# AngularJs templates not loading from $templateCache

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently building an Angular app which needs to be embedded via a script tag on any other web page.

I have decided to use some JS which builds up the app wrapper, ng-view elements etc before using `resumeBootStrap` to init the app.

I am then using a Grunt build file along with [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) to build one file which will then get called from the third party web page.

So, the initial dom building etc works fine, however, I am trying to load in the templates from `$templateCache` to load the views that we add to the built file with grunt-angular-template. I can see the templates are being added to the build file fine, however, when I try to load the third party page, I am getting errors as it is trying to load the view from the local server, not the cache/build file.

The code I have is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngScrollbar'
]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })

});
angular.module('MyApp').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  'use strict';

  $templateCache.put('views/main.html', '...')

...
```

Any advice on how to do this much appreciated, or indeed, any tips on how best to include all of my views etc so that I do not need to make remote calls to the host server to fetch the template files.

Cheers

Comment: $templateCache.put('views/main.html','contents of your Template')

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
$templateCache.put('views/main.html', $templateCache.get('views/main.html'))
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

if you use grunt

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor

Comment: Thanks, but that is essentially what the output in the built file is doing, except the second argument is the escaped output/,markup from the view file. The problem is coming in whereby $routeProvider is not reading from $templateCache in the templateUrl argument of the route definition. It is still trying to load the html file from the local server.

Comment: You should put the snippet in a run block

Comment: I have done so already? There is the run block in my original post's code.

Comment: Do you have the same code between the two files? Else it will catch the difference and load it in.

Answer (score -1):

Are you including js file generated by the grunt task in your html, I.e:

```
<script src="/templates.js"></script>
```

Comment: It should just be output in the main built file should it not?